# Kotlin generics supertype not applied

Tags: kotlin

I was coding on Java for quite a long time and trying to migrate to Kotlin. I'm confused with Generics in Kotlin a bit...

I have a `DelegateManager` class. It should consume only subtypes of `IViewData`

```
class DelegateManager<T : IViewData> {
    private val delegates: MutableList<AdapterDelegate<T>> = mutableListOf()

    fun addDelegate(adapterDelegate: AdapterDelegate<T>) {
        delegates.add(adapterDelegate)
    }
    ...
}
```

Inside `TrackListAdapter` I want to add a delegate. As you might have seen it's `AdapterDelegate<TrackViewData>` and `TrackViewData` is a subtype of `IViewData` So it should work but it shows error inside init block of `TrackListAdapter`

```
class TrackListAdapter : BaseListAdapter<IViewData>() {
    init {
        delegateManager.addDelegate(TrackViewDelegate()) // error: Type mismatch -> Required: AdapterDelegate<IViewData>, Found: TrackViewDelegate
    }
}

class TrackViewDelegate : AdapterDelegate<TrackViewData>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ListViewHolder<TrackViewData> {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.track_item, parent, false)
        return TrackViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun isDelegateForDataType(data: IViewData) = data is TrackViewData
}
```

How to deal with it? How to extend the generic parameter correctly?

Comment: Define DelegateManager's and AdapterDelegate's types as `in`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've added it but in someplace I have an error : `Type parameter T is declared as "in" but occurs "out" in out position`
If I change `in` to `out` it shows opposite error

Comment: It AdapterDelegate has to be used as both a consumer and producer, you won’t be able to put it in a list that contains versions of it for multiple different types, regardless of the hierarchy of those types.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm confused...How do you solve such problems? These restrictions break my code. It will produce spaghetti code if I will divide this class into 2(one for producing parameter and one for consuming)

Comment: You’ll have to make a higher level design decision that changes the way this works more fundamentally. I can’t recommend anything without knowing a lot more about what you’re doing. But possibly you can have a `Map<KClass<T>, MutableList<T>>` and use a reified function to add items.